# Undefined symbols when using Clang's "undefined" sanitizer

Tags: c++, macos, clang, undefined-behavior, clang++

This code compiles fine with clang's "undefined behavior" sanitizer enabled:

```
➜  ~ cat test.cc 
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Won't compile if next line will be uncommented!
  // std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  int k = 0x7fffffff;
  k += argc;
  return 0;
}
➜  ~ clang++ -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined test.cc
```

However when I uncomment mentioned line it explodes:

```
  ~ clang++ -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined test.cc   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___ubsan_handle_dynamic_type_cache_miss", referenced from:
      _main in test-5f28d3.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-5f28d3.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-5f28d3.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test-5f28d3.o
  "___ubsan_vptr_type_cache", referenced from:
      _main in test-5f28d3.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-5f28d3.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-5f28d3.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test-5f28d3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Clang version:

```
➜  ~ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Verbose compiler output is [here](https://gist.github.com/lstipakov/ff8ad16d83d47dd27af18893e29ca123).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using clang/llvm binaries from llvm site instead of Apple's clang.

Comment: In case if you recall,  how did you configure to pick user installed llvm libraries instead Apple's clang ?  It will be very helpful.